# Для бота в телеграм хранить данные лучше в программе или в базе данных?

Tags: sql, база-данных, telegram-bot, asp.net-core, бот

подскажите пожалуйста. Я использую Entity Framework Core для хранения всех пользователей бота. При старте бота я загружаю всех пользователей и все необходимое в соответствующие коллекции, так как для каждого пользователя мне нужно хранить еще пару свойств, которые я не хочу записывать в базу данных.При необходимости сохранить что-то я создаю контекст, обновляю уже имеющегося в программе пользователя и вызываю SaveChanges. Правильно ли я поступаю? Или лучше хранить все в базе данных и каждый раз посылать в нее соответствующий запрос по поиску пользователя? Спасибо.

Comment: *для каждого пользователя мне нужно хранить еще пару свойств, которые я не хочу записывать в базу данных* А откуда Вы их берёте при старте программы-то? хотя не вижу сложностей - зашифровать и потом в БД. А при получении - расшифровывать. *хранить данные лучше в программе или в базе данных?* Однозначно в БД. Ну представь, что у юзера два компа, и он с любого может запустить программу со своим профилем...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Так и сделаю. Эти свойства имеют свое стандартное значение и в ходе работы программы изменяются. Немного неуместен пример с двумя компами, так как индексация пользователя происходит через ID его аккаунта в телеграм, но я понял, что вы имели ввиду.

Comment: Главная проблема, если данные не сохранять в БД, а только в памяти, это сохранность данных. Если произойдет сбой программы или сервера (перегрузится например) или сбой железа, то все, что было в памяти - пропадет. А то, что в БД сохранили - останется.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я и так все необходимое сохраняю в бд, просто вся основная работа с пользователями происходит без ее участия, так как эти данные потерять не страшно.